# Xcode build failed “Permission denied” when using phone gap .sh files

Tags: xcode, permissions

When I get a phonegap project in xcode ,I failed to build it with a permission issue in .sh file...Is there any help?

Also, it is working fine with the developer who give me this source...I am new to PhonGap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the answer...
I have to change the file permissions..
sudo chmod 777 copy-www-build-step.sh

just move to the platforms/ios/cordova/lib and execute the above command.